# How to obtain model information from forecast package

Tags: r, forecasting, package

I have a little stupid question about `forecast` package. I want to get information about model formula. For example:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
print(fit)
```

This produces:

```
Series: WWWusage 
ARIMA(1,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.6504  0.5256
s.e.  0.0842  0.0896

sigma^2 estimated as 9.995:  log likelihood=-254.15
AIC=514.3   AICc=514.55   BIC=522.08
```

So in this case I can see that the model is `ARIMA(1,1,1)`. But I can't find how to extract this directly.

Comment: Check https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8

Comment: @Silverfish, I know, but on the page Rob Hyndman I read a message, that it's better to ask in this forum. (( Sorry for my silly question.((

Comment: I have edited to add in a reproducible example to match Rob's answer. Hopefully this is now fit to be migrated to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
as.character(fit)
```

Comment: Thank you much!! That's all I need!

Comment: Sorry, my current reputation is not enough to vote for the answer. But It's "+", many-many "+". ))))